# Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT

Tags: android, android-studio, run-app

I've got clean install of `Android Studio 2.1.2`. Just installed and run sample project (`EmPubLite`) from [this](https://commonsware.com/Android) book and nothing else.

Strange thing is that when I run app on emulator everything is fine. Android Studio is deploying apk to emulator, runs it and successfully connects to the process.
But when I'm trying to run same app on the device, I've got this error message:

[image: error message]

And this error in the Android Studio console:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT]

Error while Installing APK
```

[image: error in the console]

Despite the fact that app gets installed and successfully runs, Android Studio can't connect to the process as it thinks there is an error. If I click on the `"OK"` button, app is uninstalled and than again installed with the same error.

I've try to install app manually, through the console and if I run

```
adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.commonsware.empublite"
```

I'm getting the same error (that may mean that the problem not in the Android Studio), but (!) when I run:

```
adb install -r add-debug.apk
```

app is installed without any errors!

Moreover, the same problem appears with any sample-project that can be found on the internet.

I've started to googling and didn't find anything useful regarding **[INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT]**.

I have `Android 4.4.4` on the device, if it matters.

How can I workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After two days of searching/googling/trying I've finally found the source of  problem =)

Here it is:

[image]

On my device there is a **"Verify apps"** checkbox in the **Secutity** settings.

When I'm **unckecking** it everything is working fine!

Does anyone faced the same problem or it's just my android device? =))

Comment: Maybe @CommonsWare could comment on this?

Comment: As I told, this issue exists with **any** sample project as long as **Verify apps** is checked.

Comment: Strange. I have it enabled and have not had problems running some examples. Though, not commonsware ones. The check explicitly says "harmful" apps, which suggests there is some code that requests an unchecked permission

Comment: @cricket_007, Well, maybe it's because of version of Android itself. Mine is `4.4.4`, what is yours?

Comment: Think it's currently 5.x, but I have been developing on various devices since 2.3, and I don't remember ever needing to disable that setting

Comment: Strange, I even got this error when I'm creating a blank activity supplied by Android Studio =). And I start to think that's only my device problem, because there is no mentions on the google search about **INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT** =)

Comment: That is strange. You may need to clear the ADB authorized devices on your device, then re-authorize your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118760/discussion-between-spirit-and-cricket-007).

Comment: There's some option in the menus for "revoke usb debugging authorization"